# how to multiply a matrix by itself transposed in R

Tags: r

The first matrix

```
M1=structure(list(X1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    X0 = c(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, -0.5, 1, -0.5, 0, 
    1, 0, -4, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0.5, 0, -2, 0.5, 0, 0), X0.1 = c(1.2, 
    0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, 1, 0.5, 0, 
    0.5, 0, 2.5, -1, 0.5, -3, 0), X0.2 = c(2.8, 0, 0, 0.8, 0.2, 
    0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0, 0.5, -0.5, 0.7, -3.7, 2, 0, 0, 
    1.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, -2.5, 0), X0.3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 
    1, 0, -1, 0.5, 0, -0.5, 0.5, -1.5, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 
    1, -2.5, 0), X0.4 = c(0.5, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, -1, 
    1, 1, -1.5, 4.5, 1, -1, 0.5, 1.5, 0, 4, 0, -2, 6, 0), X0.5 = c(0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, -10L, 10L, -10L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, -3L, 
    8L, 2L, -12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 22L, 0L, -4L, 8L, 0L), X0.6 = c(0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, -12L, 14L, -12L, 13L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, -2L, 
    8L, 4L, -14L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 2L, -4L, 10L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))
```

The second (transposed intself the first matrix)

```
structure(list(X1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X1.1 = c(0.5, 
1.2, 2.8, 0, 0.5, 0, 0), X1.2 = c(0.5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2), X1.3 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X1.4 = c(0, 0.5, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0), X1.5 = c(0, 
0, 0.2, 0, 1, 2, 2), X1.6 = c(0.5, 0.5, 0, 1, 0, -10, -12), X1.7 = c(0.5, 
0, 0.5, -1, 0, 10, 14), X1.8 = c(1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, -10, -12), 
    X1.9 = c(-0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 2, 14, 13), X1.10 = c(1, 0, -0.5, 
    -1, 0, 0, 1), X1.11 = c(-0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, -1, 0, 0), X1.12 = c(0, 
    0, 0.5, 0, 1, 1, 0), X1.13 = c(1, 0, -0.5, -0.5, 1, 2, 2), 
    X1.14 = c(0, 0, 0.7, 0.5, -1.5, -3, -2), X1.15 = c(-4, -2, 
    -3.7, -1.5, 4.5, 8, 8), X1.16 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
    4L), X1.17 = c(0.5, 0.5, 0, 1, -1, -12, -14), X1.18 = c(1, 
    0, 0, -1, 0.5, 0, 0), X1.19 = c(0, 0.5, 1.5, 0, 1.5, 0, 0
    ), X1.20 = c(0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0), X1.21 = c(0, 2.5, 
    0, -1, 4, 22, 20), X1.22 = c(-2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L
    ), X1.23 = c(0.5, 0.5, 0, 1, -2, -4, -4), X1.24 = c(0, -3, 
    -2.5, -2.5, 6, 8, 10), X1.25 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

How to multiply a matrix by itself transposed. What the way There is?
The result must be some like on this picture
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `%*%`

Comment: Try `M1 %*% t(M1)` or `tcrossprod(M1)` (faster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R can handle matrix and its manipulation very well. You can use the code below to convert your ordinary dataframe to matrix, find transpose and then to multiply them:

```
# first convert dataframe to matrix
M1Matrix<-data.matrix(M1) 
M1Transpose<-t(M1Matrix)
MProd<-M1Matrix %*%  M1Transpose
```

MProd being the product of the matrix and its transpose which comes out to be below:

[image: Resultant matrix]

Comment: `*` performs element-wise multiplication. matrix multiplication is `%*%`